# How to get the main monitor window desktop area in Windows from a .NET5 app?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, .net-5, monitor

It sounds like there is a new way to call Windows API (instead of PInvoke): [Calling Windows APIs in .NET5](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2020/09/03/calling-windows-apis-in-net5/).

Is there a way to get all monitors definition (size++)? Having the main one (the number 1)? And get coordinates (top left and bottom right) of its WorkingArea (the available window space without the taskbar)?

Comment: It has been "new" for the past 9 years, beware of the meaning of "adaptive code".  The simple way is to put `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` in the project file so you can use the Screen class.

Answer (score 1):

I could be misreading [the release](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2020/09/03/calling-windows-apis-in-net5/), but I don't believe the approach has changed: you still use the same Windows Runtime (WinRT) APIs.

> .NET5 applications can now access Windows APIs through a new set of Target Framework Monikers (TFMs), which have been extended to support platform specific APIs. This is the recommended mechanism for .NET going forward. For more information on this change, please refer to the [.NET5 Preview 8 announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0-preview-8/).
>
> This change means that applications targeting .NET5 no longer need to reference the `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` NuGet package.
>
> Developers can access this functionality by installing the latest preview for .NET5 (preview 8) and Visual Studio 16.8 (preview 2).

What has changed is the way you add references to these APIs to your project. Instead of including the `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` NuGet package, you specify which operating systems/versions your project supports via Target Framework Monikers (TFMs). Adding a TFM for Windows automatically adds access to the appropriate WinRT APIs for the Windows version you specified.

There's a guide for this in the [`windows-uwp`](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/blob/docs/hub/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance.md) repo.

> ### Modify a .NET project to use Windows Runtime APIs
>
> There are several options for .NET projects:
>
> - Starting in .NET 5, you can add a Target Framework Moniker (TFM) to your project file to access WinRT APIs. This option is supported in projects that target Windows 10, version 1809 or later.
> - For earlier versions of .NET, you can install the `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` NuGet package to add all necessary references to your project. This option is supported in projects that target Windows 10, version 1803 or later.
> - If your project multi-targets .NET 5 (or later) and earlier versions of .NET, you can configure the project file to use both options.
>
> #### .NET 5 and later: Use the Target Framework Moniker option
>
> This option is only supported in projects that use .NET 5 (or a later release) and target Windows 10, version 1809 or a later OS release. For more background info about this scenario, see [this blog post](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2020/09/03/calling-windows-apis-in-net5/).
>
> 1. With your project open in Visual Studio, right-click your project in **Solution Explorer** and choose **Edit Project File**. Your project file should look similar to this.
>
>    ```xml
>    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
>      <PropertyGroup>
>        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
>        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
>      </PropertyGroup>
>    </Project>
>    ```
> 2. Replace the value of the **TargetFramework** element with one of the following strings:
>
>    - **net5.0-windows10.0.17763.0**: Use this value if your app targets Windows 10, version 1809.
>    - **net5.0-windows10.0.18362.0**: Use this value if your app targets Windows 10, version 1903.
>    - **net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0**: Use this value if your app targets Windows 10, version 2004.
>
>    For example, the following element is for a project that targets Windows 10, version 2004.
>
>    ```xml
>    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
>    ```
>
>    In later versions of .NET, you can replace the value with the relevant version, for example **net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0**.
> 3. Save your changes and close the project file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I removed the PackageReference to "Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts" without harms. I only reference: <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework> but I can't see any information about the Desktop , working area, monitors

Comment: I fallback to include Winforms because Winforms has: System.Windows.Forms.Screen.GetWorkingArea